# unable to mock panache's persistAndFlush() due to lambda expressions

Tags: lambda, mockito, junit5, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using Quarkus with hibernate-panache-orm. Below is my sample code

```
Optional<OtherObject> opt = object.getList().stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
if(opt.isPresent()){
    OtherObject obj = opt.get()
    obj.setVal("SomeVal");
    opt.persistAndFlush();
}
```

If I pass actual values for `object` from test class to main class, then `opt.persistAndFlush()` step will fail. Else not understanding how to mock `.filter(predicate)` step.
Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think your intent here is to update the object. Currently you are trying to persist the Optional which is not an Entity and cannot become a Managed Entity.

In this case just change

```
opt.persistAndFlush();
```

to

```
obj.persistAndFlush();
```